# VBA copy columns drastically increases file size

Tags: excel, vba, filesize

I have the following piece of VBA code in Excel:

```
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim des As Worksheet
Dim rows As Integer
Dim src_rows As Integer
Set src = Sheets("source sheet")
Set des = Sheets("destination sheet)

'Copy and Paste relevant columns
src.Activate
src_rows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
Range("A2:G2" & src_rows).Copy
des.Activate
Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

My aim is to copy several columns from a source sheet (this is populated by a SQL data connection) into a different sheet. The source data can change, hence I calculate how many rows there currently are using the variable `src_rows`

This code is repeated to copy other needed columns. It all works as I want it too. However, after running and saving, the file size jumps from around 5MB to around 60MB! It can't be the extra data as there's only around 10K rows. And if I delete the copied data and re-save the file does not drop back to 5MB.

I have also tried using `range(__).copy destination:= ___`, but this doesn't work.
If I manually copy, the file size doesn't increase. If I manually copy and record a macro and run this macro, the file increases.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `2` infront of the row count when copying.  Should be `Range("A2:G" & src_rows).Copy`.

I would also suggest using `RangeUsed.Rows` instead of counting down (if 2nd row is empty the `End(xlDown)` will go to the max row).

Comment: Thanks, noticed that on the others but missed it out on this one.
Incorporated UsedRange now, was looking for something better than what I've done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copy and paste committing data to the clipboard, try using VBA to set the values of one range to the other, e.g.

```
Sheets("dest").Range("A1:A100").Value = Sheets("src").Range("A1:A100").Value
```

Is more efficient than

```
Sheets("dest").Range("A1:A100").Copy
Sheets("src").Range("A1:A100").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

please see the simplied code below

```
Sub test()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim des As Worksheet
    Dim src_rows As Long
    Set src = Sheets("source sheet")
    Set des = Sheets("destination sheet")
    src.Range("A2:G" & src.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Copy des.Range("A2")
End Sub
```